# Getting null column while inserting spatial data

Tags: mysql, geospatial

I am trying to simple calculate midpoint between two point in mysql and I am constantly getting null value for column midpoint. Could anyone help to find the right solution how to insert the midpoint coordinates into midpoint column? Here is the code:

```
set @x1 = -105.00341892242432;
set @y1 = 39.75383843460583;
set @x2 = -105.0008225440979;
set @y2 = 39.751891803969535;
set @mid1 = (@x1+@x2)/2;
set @mid2 = (@y1+@y2)/2;
update line_park set midpoint = GeomFromText('POINT(@mid1,@mid2)') where id=1;
```

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to build the point string with the values by ourself

```
GeomFromText(CONCAT('POINT(' , @mid1, ' ', @mid2, ')'))
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment. It is the same situation, midpoint is null.

Comment: The point documentation says that the coordiantes are separated by a blank space instead of a comma, try this http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/de/point-property-functions.html

Answer (score 0):

The strings `@mid1` and `@mid2` won't get automatically replaced by their values. You need to do that yourself. Try

```
set @str = concat('POINT(',@mid1,@mid2,')');
update line_park set midpoint = GeomFromText(@str) where id=1;
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment. It is the same situation, midpoint is null.